# phpStorm, при попытке получить объект из connect Undefined variable '$...'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, phpstorm

Приветик, не могу разобрать, почему переменная подчёркивается красным и выдаёт ошибку в коде.

Алгоритм:
Подключаюсь к бд phpmyadmin через mysqli_connect, ошибок не происходит.
Пытаюсь подключить файл через require_once, подключение успешно, при попытке получить объект возвращаемый connect, а именно - $link, подчёркивается красным, почему?
В проблемах такая запись:
Undefined variable '$link'
Внесение изменений в бд проходит замечательно, а вот считывание не проходит, функция mysqli_num_rows возвращает нуль!

Файл signin.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'connect.php';
    session_start();

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $check_user = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_user) > 0) {

        header('Location: ../register.php');

    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
    ?>
```

Файл index.php

```
        <?php
        session_start();
    ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--form-->
    <form action="vendor/signin.php" method="post">
        <label>Логин</label>
        <input name="login" type="text">
        <label>Пароль</label>
        <input name="password" type="password">
        <button type="submit">Вход</button>
        <a href="register.php">Регистрация</a>
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
            echo '<p class="msg"> ' . $_SESSION['message'] . ' </p>';
        }
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл connect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'phpSite');

if(!$link){
    print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: `action="vendor/signin.php"` исходя из этого, структура следующая - на одном уровне файлы connect.php, index.php, register.php, а файл signin.php.в папке vendor и вы подключаете базу как если бы signin.php и connect.php лежат в одной папке, а это не так. Проблема понятна?

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ! Попробовала указать путь как вы сказали, но подчёркивание никуда не ушло и ошибка тоже на месте

Comment: Подчеркивание может и не исчезнуть, на него можно внимание не обращать с этими подключениями.. Работает или нет проверить банально - ` echo "connected"; die();` вначале файла connect.php, и когда вход нажимать увидите проблема в подключении файла или в чем-то другом, если выведется надпись "connected"